# How to save frames into file in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I'm very new in python and in Keras.
For example i generated frames

```
keras_video.utils.show_sample(gen, random=True)
```

How to save all generated frames into files? I need not show, i need to save in storage files as png.

If you also know how to save frames into new video - it will be great!

Comment: What is keras_video?

Comment: this is it https://github.com/metal3d/keras-video-generators